# pandas write dataframe to parquet format with append

Tags: python, apache, pandas, parquet

I am trying to write a `pandas dataframe` to `parquet` file format (introduced in most recent pandas version 0.21.0) in `append` mode. However, instead of appending to the existing file, the file is overwritten with new data. What am i missing?

the write syntax is

```
df.to_parquet(path, mode='append')
```

the read syntax is

```
pd.read_parquet(path)
```

Comment: [try opening the file in append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531025/1278112)

Comment: this does not work (makes not difference from the previous situation)

Comment: from this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234391/how-to-append-data-to-an-existing-parquet-file" it looks like append is not supported in parquet client API

Comment: [In the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas-dataframe-to-parquet) there is no `append` mode for `to_parquet()` API.If you want to append to a file, the `append` mode is for the file.That's what I try to express earlier.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113813/using-pyarrow-how-do-you-append-to-parquet-file

Comment: In case you want append to the SAME file, then forget my comment, but sometimes it could be usefull write the new parquet file to the same directory with another name. So, next time you cand read to the directory instead an specific file and you will get the data in every parquet file on that directory

Answer (score 26):

Looks like its possible to append row groups to already existing parquet file using [fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write). This is quite a unique feature, since most libraries don't have this implementation.

Below is from [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html):

```
DataFrame.to_parquet(path, engine='auto', compression='snappy', index=None, partition_cols=None, **kwargs)
```

we have to pass in both engine and **kwargs.

> - engine{‘auto’, ‘pyarrow’, ‘fastparquet’}
> - **kwargs - Additional arguments passed to the parquet library.

**kwargs - here we need to pass is: **append=True** (from [fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write))

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2,], 'col2': [3, 4]})
file_path = Path("D:\\dev\\output.parquet")

if file_path.exists():
  df.to_parquet(file_path, engine='fastparquet', append=True)
else:
  df.to_parquet(file_path, engine='fastparquet')
```

If append is set to True and the file does not exist then you will see below error

```
AttributeError: 'ParquetFile' object has no attribute 'fmd'
```

Running above script 3 times I have below data in parquet file.
[image]

If I inspect the metadata, I can see that this resulted in 3 row groups.

[image]

---

> #### Note:
>
> Append could be inefficient if you write too many small row groups. Typically recommended size of a row group is closer to 100,000 or 1,000,000 rows. This has a few benefits over very small row groups. Compression will work better, since compression operates within a row group only. There will also be less overhead spent on storing statistics, since each row group stores its own statistics.

Comment: I tried this with pyarrow and it failed, so it seems to only work with fastparquet as the author suggests

Comment: If you're getting `TypeError: expected list of bytes`, ensure that your `df.dtypes` are well defined (e.g. using `df = df.astype({"col1": "str", ...}`).

Answer (score 7):

To append, do this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow as pa

dataframe = pd.read_csv('content.csv')
output = "/Users/myTable.parquet"

# Create a parquet table from your dataframe
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(dataframe)

# Write direct to your parquet file
pq.write_to_dataset(table , root_path=output)
```

This will automatically append into your table.

Comment: it will create directory with few parquet files, as pyarrow dataset

Answer (score 3):

I used the awswrangler library. It works like a charm

**Below are the reference docs**

https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_parquet.html

I have read from kinesis stream and used kinesis-python library to consume the message and writing to s3 . processing logic of json I have not included as this post deals with problem unable to append data to s3. Executed in aws sagemaker jupyter

**Below is the sample code I used:**

```
!pip install awswrangler
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd
evet_data=pd.DataFrame({'a': [a], 'b':[b],'c':[c],'d':[d],'e': [e],'f':[f],'g': [g]},columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
#print(evet_data)
s3_path="s3://<your bucker>/table/temp/<your folder name>/e="+e+"/f="+str(f)
try:
    wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=evet_data,
    path=s3_path,
    dataset=True,
    partition_cols=['e','f'],
    mode="append",
    database="wat_q4_stg",
    table="raw_data_v3",
    catalog_versioning=True  # Optional
    )
    print("write successful")       
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Any clarifications ready to help. In few more posts I have read to read data and overwrite again. But as the data gets larger it will slow down the process. It is inefficient

Comment: Hey, thanks for this - it seems to create snappy.parquet files, Is there a way to create singular parquet files, or at least non-snappy files?

Comment: Oop nevermind, it has an option for compression=None.

Answer (score 1):

There is no append mode in `pandas.to_parquet()`. What you can do instead is read the existing file, change it, and write back to it overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fastparquet write function

```py
from fastparquet import write

write(file_name, df, append=True)
```

The file must already exist as I understand it.

API is available here (for now at least): https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering the use of partitions:

As per Pyarrow [doc](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset) (this is the function called behind the scene when using partitions), you might want to combine `partition_cols` with a unique `basename_template` name. i.e. something like the following:

```py
df.to_parquet(root_path, partition_cols=["..."], basename_template="{i}")
```

You could omit `basename_template` if `df` is not overlapping existing data. But if you do have overlaps, it would create duplicate `.parquet` files.

This is very handy if your partition column consists of timestamp. This way you can actually have a "rolling" DataFrame and there would be no duplicate being written, only new files corresponding to new times would get created.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas `to_parquet()` can handle both single files as well as directories with multiple files in it. Pandas will silently overwrite the file, if the file is already there. To append to a parquet object just add a new file to the same parquet directory.

```py
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

# write append (replace the naming logic with what works for you)
filename = f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()}.parquet'
df.to_parquet(os.path.join(path, filename))

# read
pd.read_parquet(path)
```

Comment: It strikes me that this would scale linearly in time, i.e. better than does `append` mode as suggested by @Naveen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64814917/1021819 - am I right? And `to_parquet()` supports S3, correct?