# Appending the parquet file while chunking

Tags: python, pandas, append, parquet

I am trying to write a  `pandas dataframe` to `parquet` file format in `append` mode. However, instead of appending to the existing file, the file is overwritten with new data. What am i missing?

the write syntax is

```
df.to_parquet(path, mode='append')
```

the read syntax is

```
pd.read_parquet(path)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use fastparquet engine for this.

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path

file_path = "D:\\dev\\output.parquet"
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2,], 'col2': [3, 4]})
if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
  df.to_parquet(file_path, engine='fastparquet')
else:
  df.to_parquet(file_path, engine='fastparquet', append=True)
```

This is described more in this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209756/6563567