# How can one append to parquet files and how does it affect partitioning?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

Does parquet allow appending to a parquet file periodically ?

How does appending relate to partitioning if any ? For example if i was able to identify a column that had low cardinality and partition it by that column, if i were to append more data to it would parquet be able to automatically append data while preserving partitioning or would one have to repartition the file ?

Comment: parquet files cannot be modified is my understanding. pyarrow does not allow appending to parquet files neither. The only option to 'append' to a partitioned parquet file is using Spark API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42140475/1157754. I'd point you to the comments under that answer though as this is not truly an 'append'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does parquet allow appending to a parquet file periodically ?

Yes and No.  The parquet spec describes a format that could be appended to by reading the existing footer, writing a row group, and then writing out a modified footer.  This process is described a bit [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1022).

Not all implementations support this operation.  The only implementation I am aware of at the moment is fastparquet (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74245281/202694)).  It is usually acceptable, less complexity, and potentially better performance to cache and batch, either by caching in memory or writing the small files and batching them together at some point later.

> How does appending relate to partitioning if any?

Parquet does not have any concept of partitioning.

Many tools that support parquet implement partitioning.  For example, pyarrow has a [datasets](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html) feature which supports partitioning.  If you were to append new data using this feature a new file would be created in the appropriate partition directory.

Comment: appending row groups to an existing parquet file is possible using fast parquet library

Comment: Hmm...I think fastparquet's append feature is used to add files to data sets and not to add row groups to existing files.

Comment: It does append a new row group.. I have posted the answer below. Its a very useful feature that I didn't know was possible.

Comment: @shadow0359 I've updated my answer to reflect that fastparquet supports this operation.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to append row groups to already existing parquet file using fastparquet.

Here is my [SO answer on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209756/6563567).

[From fast parquet docs](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write)

> append: bool (False) or ‘overwrite’ If False, construct data-set from
> scratch; if True, add new row-group(s) to existing data-set. In the
> latter case, the data-set must exist, and the schema must match the
> input data.

```
from fastparquet import write
write('output.parquet', df, append=True)
```

**EXAMPLE UPDATE:**

Here is a PY script. The first run, it will create a file with one row group. Subsequent runs, it will append row groups to the same parquet file.

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd
from fastparquet import write

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2,], 'col2': [3, 4]})
file_path = "C:\\Users\\nsuser\\dev\\write_parq_row_group.parquet"
if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
  write(file_path, df)
else:
  write(file_path, df, append=True)
```

Comment: Can you maybe include a complete example?  I have been unable to figure out how to use fastparquet to actually append to existing files.  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/westonpace/edf7a3cc7532f9b4d7d3a689ade25478) is my current test.

Comment: @Pace could you check this answer? I have added the example here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209756/6563567

Comment: @Pace I have updated the gist with example.

Comment: That works great, thanks.  I was getting the 'fmd' error and hadn't realized I needed to leave off `append` on the first call.

Answer (score 0):

exactly. Whether appending data using fastparquet depend on situation:

1. If every peace of your data is very small like 10mb. This case would harm the performance slightly. I recommend you reconstruct to big peace periodly. A appropriate size of every parquet file is 500mb ~ 1Gb.
2. If every peace of your data is big enough, this case would not harm your performance.