# How to append data to existing Parquet from Polars

Tags: append, parquet, python-polars, writefile

I have multiple `polars` dataframes and I want to append them to an existing Parquet file.

`df.write_parquet("path.parquet")` overwrites the existing parquet file. How can I append?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars does not support appending to Parquet files, and most tools do not, see for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124332/how-can-one-append-to-parquet-files-and-how-does-it-affect-partitioning).

Your best bet would be to cast the dataframe to an Arrow table using `.to_arrow()`, and use [pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset). In particular, see the comment on the parameter `existing_data_behavior`. Still, that requires organizing your data in partitions, which effectively means you have a separate parquet file per partition, stored in the same directory. So each `df` you have, becomes its own parquet file, and you abstract away from that on the read. Polars does not support writing partitions as far as I'm aware. There is support for reading though, see [the source argument in pl.read_parquet](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_parquet.html).

Comment: Thank you! I will think about it. So simple if Polars not support it, I can convert df to pandas and use hdf5 as usually..